# Can I access localhost from multiple virtual clients with Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, client-server

I'm learning to program java enterprise edition applications (web applications). to test the correctness of my coding i need multiple clients to access my project simultaneously (i.e test concurency), the projects are deployed with glassfish and accessed on the localhost, i tried to use multiple web-browsers unfortunatly the result interpreted tells me that i am only accessing my project withe the same client, so this is my question:

Can I access localhost from multiple virtual clients with Glassfish?

Do you have a name for tools to simulate virtual clients from the same machine to test my coding?

Edit: what i need is to access my project with some sort of browser client for multiple concurrent users, to test something like a board game or a chat application.

Answer (score 1):

Not with localhost; but you need to find the ip address of your server. Then using servers ip address you can test as **127.12.13.45:8080/app**

So using ip address in place of localhost; you can test your app from different client machines.

Apart from this; you can also use some of the testing tools which allows you to simulate multiple clients from the same machine.

Comment: 1) Is there a particular way to tell the ip address of the server?
2) At this point it won't be practical for me to access my localhost from a different client machine as i won't always have access to two computers.
3) The last part of your answer is what i was researching on the net, cause i couldn't find this tools i posted my question, so do you have a name for a tool that servers this purpose?

Comment: in this case I suggest to launch glassfish domain with IP 0.0.0.0 This way it will be available on all network interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)?  It can (among many other things) simulate multiple concurrent users.

Comment: After taking an overview to JMeter it sounds very useful & i would use it for sure, the thing is it won't do in my case, what i need is to access my project with some sort of browser client for multiple concurrent users, to test something like a board game or a chat app.